# How to load thumbnail with Universal Image Loader for Android?

Tags: android, thumbnails, universal-image-loader

I am using this lib:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

I want to load an image thumbnail into an ImageView using the lib.

What content uri can I pass into:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView); //?
```

The docs give an example of using a content url:

```
String imageUri = "content://media/external/audio/albumart/13"; // from content provider
```

I pretty much want to switch from doing this:

```
 return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

to using the lib.

As you can see I have the id but I need to construct a url for MICRO_KIND image thumbnails...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use next URI format: `content://media/external/images/thumbnails/13`

```
String uri = "content://media/external/images/thumbnails/" + id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible to also specify the MICRO_KIND or some other size too?